# How can use an alias() array in Graphite?

Tags: graphite, grafana, collectd

I'm currently using the following aliasByMetric function to measure different memory utilization metrics:

```
aliasByMetric($prefix.$server.memory.memory.{cached,free,buffered})
```

How can I add an alias (so it reads correctly on the legend) that includes the cached, free, and buffered value?

I've tried a number of queries, including:

```
alias(aliasByMetric($prefix.$server.memory.memory.{cached,free,buffered}), {cached,free,buffered})
```

but haven't had any luck. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming the alias in the first case (node 4) is the server name? And you want both the server name and the metric name (cached/free/buffered)? Your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: The syntax you're after just doesn't exist, there are no arrays or anything like that, but if you're a bit clearer about the end result you want it might be possible.

Comment: How can I customize the legend when using: aliasByMetric($prefix.$server.memory.memory.{cached,free,buffered}) into three other values?